# Grpc Writing Interceptors for Specific Endpoint

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

I implemented a grpc server in Golang. This server has multiple endpoints, but for one of the endpoints I want to implement an interceptor that will check the validity of an authentication token before proceeding with the request. I know how to implement an interceptor that will run when a request reaches any of the grpc endpoints, but how can I make so that my interceptor only runs for one specific endpoint?

Comment: Inside a grpc interceptor you can know the method of the request. I think you can just do nothing for the other endpoints that you don't care about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those interested, I was able to find the method of the request by inspecting the grpc.UnaryServerInfo param of the interceptor. There is an attribute called FullMethod that gives you the the endpoint of the request.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the method name and compare when you are getting a request through your interceptor. Your custom interceptor will have one component called [ServerInfo](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#UnaryServerInfo) which will help you to filter from which method you are getting called. Based on that, you can filter out your authentication endpoint